# Books on difference hierachy

Tags: logic, reference-request, book-recommendation, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

The wonderful book '[Descriptive Set Theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-4190-4)' by Kechris provides a rich theory on the [Borel Hierachy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy) (Chapter $22$). 
I am especially interested in the section $22$E 'The Difference Hierachy', which states that every set in the class $\Delta_{\xi+1}$ can be separated by transfinite difference of $\Pi_\xi.$

> Question: Other than the above mentioned book, in what book can I look
>   for to gain more information on difference hierachy?

Answer (score 0):

I offer you to download this book: [Kanamori "A The Higher Infinite Large Cardinals In Set Theory"](https://archive.org/details/1kanamoriATheHigherInfiniteLargeCardinalsInSetTheory)

Also you can check: [Early investigation of Borel degrees](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~plaice/archive/WWW/2008/P-08-Borel.pdf)

[The Wadge Hierarchy: Beyond Borel Sets](http://my.unil.ch/serval/document/BIB_0B4E22D7D1C0.pdf)

Comment: While I'm happy to know about the article by Wadge, I think explicitly linking to an illegal download of a text is inappropriate for this site. (Also, that book is *huge*; you should cite some part of it rather than the whole thing.)